# Странное поведение __str__ при композиции классов

Tags: python, классы, наследование, вложенные-классы

При попытке вызова метода `__str__` у класса `Robot` должны сработать `__str__` у его вложенных классов `Laser`, `Claw` и `SmartPhone`. Однако, при выводе вместо ожидаемого:

> Laser disintegrate
> Claw crush
> Smart Phone ring

Получается следующее:

> Laser (<**main**.Laser object at 0x7fb2885f1fa0>,)
> Claw (<**main**.Claw object at 0x7fb288617d90>,)
> Smart Phone: ring

Корректное значение при выводе зависит от порядка инициализации в конструкторе класса `Robot`, т.е. кто последний инициализирован, у того `__str__` отработает нормально.

В чем может быть причина подобного поведения?

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def does(self):
        return self.value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


class Laser(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)


class Claw(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)


class SmartPhone(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)


class Robot:
    def __init__(self, laser, claw, smart_phone):
        self.laser = Laser(laser),
        self.claw = Claw(claw),
        self.smart_phone = SmartPhone(smart_phone)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Laser {self.laser}\nClaw {self.claw}\nSmart Phone: {self.smart_phone}"


values = ['disintegrate', 'crush', 'ring']
robot = Robot(*values)

print(robot)
```

Comment: повторы "name" могут быть причиной.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Причина такого поведения в запятых в конце следуюших строк, которые превращают соответствующие переменные в кортежи (`tuple`):

```
    self.laser = Laser(laser),
    self.claw = Claw(claw),
```

уберите их и все заработает правильно:

```
In [93]: class Robot:
    ...:     def __init__(self, laser, claw, smart_phone):
    ...:         self.laser = Laser(laser)
    ...:         self.claw = Claw(claw)
    ...:         self.smart_phone = SmartPhone(smart_phone)
    ...:
    ...:     def __str__(self):
    ...:         return f"Laser {self.laser}\nClaw {self.claw}\nSmart Phone: {self.smart_phone}"
    ...:

In [94]: robot = Robot(*values)

In [95]: print(robot)
Laser disintegrate
Claw crush
Smart Phone: ring
```

PS если присвоить переменной какое-нибудь значение и поставить после этого значения запятую, то в переменную попадет кортеж (`tuple`), первым элементом которого будет указанное до запятой значение.

Пример:

```
In [86]: a = 1,

In [87]: type(a)
Out[87]: tuple

In [88]: print(a)
(1,)
```

Comment: Обилен Питон граблями, ох обилен )

Comment: @CrazyElf, это не грабли, это возможность отличить кортеж от указания явного приоритета, IMO ;) Пример: `(1+2) * 3` - парсер поймет, что `(1+2)` - не кортеж, а явное указание приоритета операций...